# webpack Error: Cannot find module 'commander'

Tags: npm, webpack, nvm, node-commander, webpack-cli

I get an error when I run in the CLI `./node_modules/.bin/webpack index.js --mode=development`

Here's the error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
Require stack:
- /home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/arg-parser.js
- /home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /home/jon/Coding/Random/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:745:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/arg-parser.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/arg-parser.js',
    '/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/home/jon/.nvm/versions/node/v15.1.0/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/home/jon/Coding/Random/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

`npm commander -v` confirms that I have **commander** installed. I'm on **Linux Mint** and have installed **npm** using **nvm**.

I'm new to npm so I don't really understand the output.

Comment: "npm commander -v" shows the npm version number and ignores the commander argument. Try "npm ls commander" to check if commander is installed in your package.

Comment: @shadowspawn  just tried that, looks like it's installed:
`random@1.0.0 /home/jon/Coding/Random
├── commander@2.20.3
├─┬ webpack-cli@4.2.0
│ └── commander@6.2.0
└─┬ webpack@5.4.0
  └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.0.3
    └─┬ terser@5.3.8
      └── commander@2.20.3 deduped`

Comment: Any success @MihailMarian ?

Comment: @Trip I think I managed to get over it but I forgot how, sorry 